# Why doesn't network engineering support questions and tags of Internet protocols?

Tags: discussion

Earlier, I was trying to ask a question related to Internet protocols, as the question was related to networking, I tried to ask the question on Network Engineering, but the site does not contain the appropriate tags like ftp, sftp, http, etc. Though, I was able to ask the question on server fault, but shouldn't network engineering be supporting question about Internet protocols?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Network Engineering supports questions about network protocols which are not above OSI layer-4. The protocols you mention about are applications or application-layer protocols.

If you ask about those protocols on NE, you will be redirected to Server Fault for a business network, or Super User for a personal network.

You can always check [What topics can I ask about here?](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this type of information.